# WPF - Setting DataContext increases computing time tremendously

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, mvvm, datacontext

After several weeks of trying to improve the performance of my application I'm asking the question here:

Scenario: 
A View is created when the user selects a Person out of a DataGrid. The View contains a ListView as menu and a ContentControl where custom UserControls are displayed.

My problem occurs when the DataContext of the view is set - it takes 31 (!!!) seconds to finish the InitializeComponent-Method when set in the constructor (see image below).
[image: Constructor for view]

However, if I don't set the DataContext to the ViewModel, as shown in the image above, the method is finished in the blink of an eye.

I already tried to optimize my XAML and paid attention to the performance of every control but it did not help.

My class-structur of the important ViewModels for the View is as follows:

- PersonViewModel : ViewModelBase (used when a normal person is openend)
- InteressentViewModel : PersonViewModel
- StudentViewModel : InteressentViewModel

In my view I have bindings on Properties and values of the ViewModel like Collections, simple values like Strings, and so on. For the simple values the binding is set to the Context Property loaded from EF.

My Question: 
**What could be the reason that setting the DataContext takes so much time?**

**EDIT 1:**
It also takes so long when I set the DataContext after the Control is Loaded, in the "Loaded" Event.

**EDIT 2:**
Image of Profiler:
[image: profiler]
This is how it looks, when I set the DataContext in the Loaded event (Time is needed for AppCode).

When I set it in the Constructor, the InitializeComponent takes ~30secs and the Profiler states the time is needed for parsing (see comments). Constructor of ViewModel is finished after 0,5 secs in Debug-Mode.

**EDIT 3**:
this is how my constructor of the Student-ViewModel looks like:

```
public StudentViewModel_v2(T_StudentInVertiefung student) : base(student.T_Interessent)
        {
        // Simple Initialisations
        // loading the context object from the DataBase to a T_StudentInVertiefung Object from the viewModel
        _Student = student;
        ... some more code

        // List initialisations
        ... about 20 ObservableCollections

        // thesis values
        AvailableThesisStates = new ObservableCollection<T_Abschlussarbeitsstatus>();
        AvailableGrades = new ObservableCollection<T_Gesamtpraedikat>();
        AvailableLecturers = new ObservableCollection<T_Vortragender>();

        // set the type of person
        Typ = PersonTyp.STUDENT;
        // Load data values
        // test, if a connection is possible
        if (IngeniumEducationEntities.TestConnection())
        {
            // available options
            // loading values for ComboBox Selection
            #region available options
            AvailableStates = new List<T_Personenstatus>(_dbContext.
                T_Personenstatus.OrderBy(s => s.Bezeichnung));

            #endregion
        }

        // commands
        ... several command initialisations
    }
```

the class itself is derived from another ViewModel where the constructor looks about the same. Calling the constructor is finished after ~0,5s in DebugMode.

The Binding in the View looks like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Person.Vorname, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
```

For each type of person (normal, student, alumni, e.g.) different views are available. To bind to a column from the database, e.g. the first name, I put the Binding on the Context-Property stored in the ViewModel like in the code above.

What I forgot say is that it doesn't takes much time everytime when opening a new view. Sometimes it's finished right away and anothertime it takes ~30s.

Comment: You can use visual studio diagnostics tools/perfview to find out caveat

Comment: If you want to do it by yourself then:
Step 1: Run it in Release mode
Step 2: Use stop watch to pin point where is leg coming from
Step 3: Repeat step 2 until you reach code which is consuming CPU time
Step 4: Improve performance of your code and measure it
Step 5: Still feel the pain? post your code on Stackoverflow with whatever you've done so far for someone to guide you

Comment: Are there properties which have a long running getter, e.g. returning values recalculated on each call of the getter? What about the constructor of your viewmodel? How much time takes it to run the constructor of the viewmodel?

Comment: using `DependencyObject` instead of `INotifyPropertyChanged` can also speed up runtime. also Debug mode is very slower than **Release mode **. try some breakpoints in viewmodel callbacks to see everything is executed once (or at least no a hundred times!!)

Comment: I agree with @Steffen, this smacks of properties serializing in data from a database or something. Can you try stubbing all your data? Also do you having any very large lists anywhere? This can happen when you template items in a ListBox (et al) and then accidentally break the virtualization.

Comment: @DipenShah: already did this. When I set the context in the constructor of my view, it states that ~30 secs are needed for WPF parsing, which is why I first paid attention to my XAML Code. If I move it to the "Loaded" event, the diagnostic tool says ~30 secs are needed for AppCode.

I work with Entity Framework and to save Code the only properties I have are the context (e.g. T_Person as entity) and the 1:m - values as ObservableCollections. None of the collection which are loaded on start-up have more than 6-10 values.

the constructor is finished in Debug-Mode after 0,5 secs

Comment: @kai Jauk You might wanna check property getters in your ViewModel, I think wpf is requesting values from DqtaContext and blocking it somewhere. Profile your view model and don't be shy to post your code over here.

Comment: @Kai Jauk: How do you intialize/fill all your observable collections with data? Do you create the ObservableCollections in ViewModel constructor, assign them to public properties, which are bound in view and fill them later item by item by accessing the database, e.g linq queries and foreach enumeration? At which state/event do you fill your collections/load the data? Do you have any linq queries in property getters?

Comment: I load the Person Entity with "include(...)" from the database and initialize the observable collections for combobox selection like this: `AvailableFieldsOfStudy = new List<T_Studienrichtung>(_dbContext.
                T_Studienrichtung.AsNoTracking());` 

or for the person like:  `_TitelZuPerson = new ObservableCollection<T_TitelZuPerson>(person.T_TitelZuPerson);`

Comment: @Kai Jauk: When you wrote "<TextBox Text="{Binding Person.Vorname, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />": how do you assign the Person property of your view model? Is it a normal getter simply returning a backing field of your view model or is Person object retrieved by using a query every time you call the getter?

Comment: it was set like this in the constsructor: `_Person = person;` whereas `person` is first retrieved from the context. So as far as I know, I retrieve it once and store it in my "T_Person" field in the ViewModel and get it with a simple getter. My attempt now is, to declare for each column/property of the entitiy-object a field in my ViewModel and see If that helps. I'll let you know.

Comment: @Kai Jauk: before rewriting your view model, you can try to use "divide and conquer". Simply comment out first half of your code. Run your program, if it is fast then the problem should be located in previously commented and inactive code. Uncomment this part and comment the other. Run again. If it is slow, then comment next half of your currently active xaml code. Run again. Repeat this until you get a part which is slow. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teile-und-herrsche-Verfahren)

Answer (score 1):

If you moved the datacontext assignment to Loaded eventhandler and the performance hit is moving to Loaded event too, then you have a long running data access in your properties which let the binding process slow down.

Try to load the data from database asynchronously before/in parallel and change your properties (getter) to present only already loaded data, e.g. stored/cached data in a backing field of your view model.

Check your data access to the database too. Maybe you can improve the database access too by adding proper indexes on the involved tables.

Comment: When I don't set the Context object - just creating the viewmodel with default constructor, no data loading - the datacontext setting does not lag. 

how can I improve it than? should I create a field for each column?